# JavaDoc - Can I divide methods into groups?

Tags: java, javadoc

I am currently creating the documentation for a class with many functions.
Is there any way to organize the JavaDoc such that the methods in the overview are divided into a few categories?

Comment: Put the groups of methods in different classes?

Comment: In theory, you could write a custom doclet for JavaDoc, but be warned, there be dragons: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

Comment: In practice, you can do a subset of that using a HTML table in the main comment. See BlockingQueue: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: If splitting up your actual class is no option, you might consider having multiple interfaces which group your functionality and where you put your documentation.

Comment: Doxygen is capable of doing this. There should be no need to refactor the code in order to properly document it. If the standard doclet can't do it, that's just it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try to refactor it so you don't have "many functions" inside one class.
It is much better to divide code into small fractions that are easier for maintaining, readability, testing, debugging, documenting etc..

Answer (score 3):

The JavaDoc tool does not have such a functionality. Even the JDK's methods aren't grouped in such a fashion.

Comment: By "JavaDoc tool" you mean the standard doclet, right?

Comment: @PedroLamarão yes, but it's more than that. AFAIK, different doclets may only decide how to render Javadoc tags. There's no Javadoc tag[s] for grouping methods, so changing the doclet you're using won't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid its not **Javadoc** - but **doxygen** supports grouping items in the output.

I've used [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) in preference to Javadoc for personal projects, and for multi-language projects professionally.  The documentation comment format is close enough to Javadoc for the most part, but I've found it much richer and extendable, and the output is just better.

Heck, for one project we published the Users Guide and API Guide as PDF through doxygen...